# jquery 1.8.2 zip has version 1.4.2 js file

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I downloaded jquery-ui-1.8.2.zip first via a link provided in the official jQuery page and then from google sources.
When unzipped, they both contained 'jquery-1.4.2.js'.

I am trying to use the "automcomplete" feature which should be in the 1.8 package, but when using the file from the mentioned zip, I only get "TypeError: $("#inputId").autocomplete is not a function".

Seems like the jquery file is indeed the the same as the name says.

I also tried loading an earlier version of jQuery (1.8.16). The zip had "jquery-1.6.2.js".

Now please explain if there is a reason for this. For me it seems erroneous.
Our project is currently using jQuery 1.7.2.

Also the version 1.8.14 zip has jquery-1.5.1.js.

Comment: I get the latest jQuery version when I download jQuery UI stable release. And the function you described to be missing has nothing to do with the jQuery version but rather with jQueryUI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing jQuery with jQuery-UI.  The latest version of jQuery is 1.7.2, the latest version of jQuery-UI is 1.8.22.  jQuery-UI requires a minimum of jQuery 1.3.2 to function, so be sure you're including both files in your page, with jQuery loaded first.

Comment: Ok. That explains. Have to look more accurately what's the deal with the "autocomplete".

Comment: Also, note that 1.8.16 is actually a higher version than 1.8.2 - see here: http://jqueryui.com/docs/Changelog

Answer (score 0):

it works for me, Jquery1.8 it must be your browser cache, in any case you all you have to do is download it and replace jquery with the lastest version of the jquery...